Why do some out-of-bounds array elements behave differently than others in C?
When trying to print addresses and values of an array element, which is not covered by the index of the array, why do some elements return:

(nil) pointer
Address of other elements in the array
Random addresses (I presume these are physical memory addresses)

My program:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int arr[5];
        arr[0]=1;
        arr[1]=2;
        arr[2]=3;
        arr[3]=4;
        arr[4]=5;
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[0], arr[0]);
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[1], arr[1]);
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[2], arr[2]);
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[3], arr[3]);
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[4], arr[4]);
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[5], arr[5]);
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[6], arr[6]);
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[7], arr[7]);
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[8], arr[8]);
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[9], arr[9]);
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[10], arr[10]);
        printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[11], arr[11]);
}

My Output is:
1   -   0x1
2   -   0x2
3   -   0x3
4   -   0x4
5   -   0x5
0   -   (nil)           // (nil is printed here)
1367157456  -   0x517d2ad0  // (random address and value)
32628   -   0x7f74          // (random address and value, which should have been adjacent, I think)
1   -   0x1         // (address and value of other element in array)
0   -   (nil)           // (here too, nil is printed)
1365029450  -   0x515cb24a
32628   -   0x7f74



Compiled with gcc [gcc ./temp.c]
x86 64 Bit Linux machine.


Not quite the same but in some C implementations a null pointer passed to printf which it should deference (e.g. char * to satisfy %s) is output as say (null) instead of allowing invalid memory to be accessed.

Re "random address and value, which should have been adjacent, I think". No, you aren't printing the address of the fictitious array element. You are printing the supposed value in decimal, and again as if its value were a pointer.

You have done two things to invoke undefined behavior, which means anything can happen, including (but most certainly not limited to) the behavior you've seen.

You're accessing an array out of bounds.
You're using the %p format specifier for an int value. This is why your out of bounds memory addresses appear to be random rather than the sequential addresses you probably expected to see: because they aren't memory addresses but rather in this case you are seeing whatever indeterminate values were past the bounds of the array.

In the latter case you may have meant:
printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[11], (void *)&arr[11]);

Or:
printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[11], (void *)(arr + 11));

General advice
As an aside, your code should use a loop from 0 to 11 to avoid all of that repetition.
for (size_t i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    printf("%d\t-\t%p\n", arr[i], (void *)&arr[i]);
}

And you'd probably be better off initializing that array more tersely.
int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

